# Equivalent of Cut() function in SparkR

Tags: r, sparkr

I am trying to create a variable that contains "buckets" of a numeric value in another column.  For example:

```
nts$size_bucket<-cut(nts$loansize, c(0, 5000,10000, 25000,50000,100000,200000,300000, 500000,Inf),
            c('<$5K', '5-10K', '10-25K', '25-50K', '50-100K', '100-200K', '200-300K', '300-500K', '500K+'))
```

In normal R, cut would work perfectly, but it doesn't appear to work with a SparkR dataframe and gives the exception:

```
'x' must be numeric
```

even though x is numeric.

Any suggestions for how to accomplish this in SparkR?

Thanks!

Comment: The error is pointing to a mismatch of the type of the first argument to cut.What does `class(nts$loansize)` return?

Comment: It's numeric, but the problem is that it's a column in a SparkR dataframe, not a regular R vector

Comment: The code in `cut` that returns that error message is     `if (!is.numeric(x)) 
        stop("'x' must be numeric")` so I'm still thinking that your object passed from Spark is failing that test and may need to be coerced via `as.numeric`.